# Strange behavior with f:ajax: Toggle between views does not update rendered code in browser if <ui:repeat> has an <h:outputText> with escape="false"

Tags: ajax, jsf

I want to switch between two views and report two lists outputs on each view.

1. Toggle between views uses a *<h:commandLink*> with an *<f:ajax*> element.
2. Each view generates the output of the lists with *<ui:repeat*>
3. The output works fine, if the *<h:outputText*> within the *<ui:repeat*> does not specify the escape attribute.

After adding *escape="true"* to the *<h:outputText*> the following happens:

1. After clicking the *<commandLink*> the *<commandLink*> the browser does not update the rendered output.
2. After clicking the myController.toggleView changes listData.showFirst (boolean)
3. After clicking the *<commandLink*> the source code of the website changes to what should be there.

**Summary:** Clicking the *<commandLink*> updates the outputed source code, but the browser does not update the output, when the *<h:outputText*> in the *<ui:repeat*> uses the attribute escape="true".

Here the code:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
  <h:commandLink actionListener="#{ myController.toggleView }" value="Click">
    <f:ajax render="@form" />
  </h:commandLink>

  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ listData.showFirst }" id="firstView">
    <ui:repeat var="house" value="#{ listData.houses }">
      <h:outputText value="#{ house.description }" escape="false" />
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup>

  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{ !listData.showFirst }" id="secondView">
    <ui:repeat var="street" value="#{ listData.streets }">
      <h:outputText value="#{ street.description }" escape="false" />
    </ui:repeat>
  </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Any ideas?